# SBJSON, check if data is done loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, sbjson

I am using SBJSON to parse data, and I want to know if there is a method to notify when the data is done loading/retrieving.

For example, when I launch the app, I want to show a splash screen when I am parsing data, and when its done, I want to show a new view.

I am building an app for ios 4 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the streaming parser API. Or just do the parsing on a background thread and notify the main thread when done. GCD is your friend there.